# How to make the legs of a whole roasted duck less fatty?

Tags: duck

I made a roast duck for Thanksgiving. It came out well.  I'm looking to improve it.

The recipe calls to pierce the skin all over, and submerge in simmering water for nearly an hour before roasting.  This helps to render a lot of fat.

The breast was marvelous.  But the leg quarters had very persistent fat.

Does anyone have a success story on how to get the legs and thighs less fatty?

Comment: Ducks are fat, you can trim the fat off, but really if you want less fat pick a different animal. Or just cook duck breasts.

Comment: 'Simmer' is kinda vague.  I suspect there'd be an ideal temperature for this (hot enough to render without cooking too much)

Comment: Simmer is in no way vague.  It is the action that occurs between still, heated water, and a rolling boil.  If anything, when cooking this it tended more towards a boil.

Comment: I have often had oriental roasted ducks which were roasted hanging, I believe with extra slits low on the thighs to allow extra fat to drain into the body cavity with the neck tied to retain it until purchased.  Note, the fat is often considered the most sought after part of the roasted bird, so in these shops purchasing one would include a couple ladles of the fat, and constant fights as to if the shop was shorting the customers a fair amount.  Rendered duck fat is often referred to as kitchen gold.

Comment: PS, it is also common to remove the legs before roasting pan style or preparing just duck breast and preparing them separate confit, slow cooked in their own fat.